# Facebook API Unsupported Operation for v2.3 but Valid for v2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using the FB Graph API using v2.3. I write the access token in the input field. Example api call is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/461151203975788/insights
```

It is now returning

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "B5syG3OvxBJ"
  }
}
```

However, when I use v2.6, it returns me all of the Insights data that is expected. I am 100% sure the access token is correct. This is happening to all the different pages I have access to. It has been working a few days ago, but it seems to be happening right after I started testing v2.6.

I suspect that *somehow*, my v2.3 usage has been blocked after using v2.6, as if Facebook is forcing me to use their newest API version.

Comment: I am getting this as well. I did not specify any version in the API and Page Insights simply does not work since a few days. Their 2.6 version returns data that takes less size and is structured differently.

Comment: @CyrilJoudieh Hi Cyril, I eventually upgraded my API calls to v2.6 and had to update my access tokens. I couldn't figure out why this was the case.

Comment: Hi Bran, I just upgraded my API engine to 2.6 and I had to change the way it parses the file. There are new metrics as well.